# How to upload ldif file to ldap Samba-dc server?

Tags: samba, ldap, ldif

For local development I docker compose file like that:

```
version: '3.4'

networks:
  dsm:

services:
  samba:
    image: instantlinux/samba-dc:latest
    container_name: samba-dc
    cap_add:
      - CAP_SYS_ADMIN
    hostname: inno.tech
    environment:
      DOMAIN_ACTION: provision
      REALM: my.company
    volumes:
      - etc:/etc/samba
      - lib:/var/lib/samba
    ports:
      - "389:389"
    secrets:
      - samba-admin-password

volumes:
  etc:
  lib:

secrets:
  samba-admin-password:
    file: secrets.yaml
```

Also I up the same server in tests using testContainers

```
val adminPasswordFile = getSecretPassword(ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:$SECRET_FILE_NAME"))
        val domainName = getDomainName(ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:$APPLICATION_CONFIG_FILENAME"))

val secretPathInContainer = "/run/secrets/samba-admin-password"
// Create and start the container
return GenericContainer(SAMBA_IMAGE)
        .withEnv("DOMAIN_ACTION", "provision")
        .withEnv("REALM", domainName)
        .withEnv(
            "ADMIN_PASSWORD_SECRET",
            adminPasswordFile,
        )
        .withPrivilegedMode(true)
        .withExposedPorts(389)
        .withCopyToContainer(
            MountableFile.forClasspathResource(SECRET_FILE_NAME, Transferable.DEFAULT_FILE_MODE),
            secretPathInContainer,
        )
```

In both cases I would like to have an ability to load LDAP data (for example on startup but it is not mandatory) for both cases but mostly for tests.

I already have **ldif** file so I started to investigate it (but if there are other ways to do it - I am ready to use them)

Source my ideas is https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Back_up_and_Restoring_a_Samba_AD_DC#Offline.2Flocal_DC_backup

I've found the command:

```
sudo samba-tool domain backup restore --backup-file=<tar-file> --newservername=<DC-name> --targetdir=<new-samba-dir>
```

But **tar** file is used here.

Based on https://lists.samba.org/archive/samba/2018-November/219439.html

and

[image: executn]

**It also works only with tar files**.

To be honest I tried to make backup using the command but no luck(it just hangs):
[image]

If I add **sudo** in the begining - I see error that `sudo: not found`
and I have no idea what to do next.

Also I've met this link:

https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Administer_Unix_Attributes_in_AD_using_samba-tool_and_ldb-tools

Wheere I've found command

```
ldbmodify -H /usr/local/samba/private/sam.ldb /tmp/group.ldif -U Administrator
```

but when I tried to execute it I've got an error:

Unable to open tdb '/usr/local/samba/private/sam.ldb': No such file or directory

```
Failed to connect to '/usr/local/samba/private/sam.ldb' with backend 'tdb': Unable to open tdb '/usr/local/samba/private/sam.ldb': No such file or directory
Failed to connect to /usr/local/samba/private/sam.ldb - Unable to open tdb '/usr/local/samba/private/sam.ldb': No such file or directory
```

is there way to upload file somehow ?